# What is groovy equivalent to java datetime code

Tags: java, groovy

### Working java Code

```
public static DateTime convertToUTC(String date) throws ParseException {        

    DateTimeParser[] parsers = {
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd" ).getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" ).getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ" ).getParser(),
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ" ).getParser()};

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append( null, parsers ).toFormatter();


    DateTime dtime = new DateTime(formatter.parseDateTime(date),DateTimeZone.UTC);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
    return formatter.print(dtime );
}
```

Groovy code i was trying, but getting exception, getting exception which was given at the bottom.

```
import org.joda.time.format.*
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone
import org.joda.time.DateTime

def input = message.getInvocationProperty('after').toString()
DateTimeParser[] parsers = [[DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd" ).getParser()],[DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" ).getParser()],[DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ" ).getParser(),DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ" ).getParser()]]
def formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append( null, parsers ).toFormatter()
return formatter.print(new DateTime(formatter.parseDateTime(input),DateTimeZone.UTC))
```

> Root Exception stack trace:
>     org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$Composite@755ed6df]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser(org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$Composite)

Comment: you could get rid of a lot copy and paste code with: `def parsers = ["yyyy-MM-dd", ...].collect{ DateTimeFormat.forPattern(it).getParser() }`

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTimeParser[] parsers = ...
```

The above code line actually created an ArrayList instead of Array. try

```
def formatter = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append( null, parsers.toArray() ).toFormatter()
```

Comment: also his parsers list is actually a list of lists.  the inner [] around the date time formatter builders are not needed.